# Are there any limits in using a PHP framework?

Tags: php, yii, frameworks, limit

I'm planning to use a PHP framework (Yii) for my future project due to the amount of features that it would contain. I have done a few PHP projects in the past and I now realize how disorganized they can get after a while, even if you use a proper directory structure. So, basically, **I'm wondering if everything in PHP, can also be done in a framework without tweaking the core framework itself. Will there be any limits? Can I use PHP classes like geolocation, phpexcel or phpthumb: http://phpthumb.gxdlabs.com? Preferably Yii.** Thank you!

Comment: Why would you ever want to tweak the core framework? Unless you ran into bugs, there is no need for that, and that goes with any language you use.

Comment: You misunderstood that statement. Let me rephrase that: Would I need to tweak the core framework if I desire any complex features for my site?

Comment: @MicoAbrina You shouldn't ever have to edit the framework itself.. or any library for that matter. Editing those files breaks the upgrade path. All code that's not yours should be extended.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if everything in PHP, can also be done in a framework without tweaking the core framework itsel

No, every framework has its limits but some are more flexible than others. For example, some frameworks don't allow you to connect to multiple data-sources with their model implementation. But if it's a decent framework, you should be able to extend or swap out those shortcomings with your own or another implementation.

> Can I use PHP classes like geolocation, phpexcel or phpthumb

Yes, most frameworks allow easy integration with other libraries. I found a link showing how to integrate phpexcel with Yii:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/101/how-to-use-phpexcel-external-library-with-yii/

Comment: Do you have any other examples for the limitations that some frameworks contain? Thank you!

Comment: @MicoAbrina Identifying pros/cons for frameworks gets too subjective for Stackoverflow. Unless you can specifically state what you're requirements are you're better-off asking that question elseware. You can also browse the [PHP+Framework tags](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+%5Bframeworks%5D+best)

Comment: Since you mentioned PHPExcel I had a issue that you could run into: http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/266713

Answer (score 0):

Yes All framworks have proscons, but it's very important that how we will user them, i.e cakephp provide the helper class to create html and form but no need to use each and every time that because it will make slow your application
CakePHP have also cache memory limitation, we found in one popular auction script.